# Code for a simple JavaScript countdown timer?

Tags: jquery, timer, counter, setinterval, clearinterval

I want to use a simple countdown timer starting at 30 seconds from when the function is run and ending at 0. No milliseconds. How can it be coded?

Answer (score 260, accepted):

```
var count=30;

var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

function timer()
{
  count=count-1;
  if (count <= 0)
  {
     clearInterval(counter);
     //counter ended, do something here
     return;
  }

  //Do code for showing the number of seconds here
}
```

To make the code for the timer appear in a paragraph (or anywhere else on the page), just put the line:

```
<span id="timer"></span>
```

where you want the seconds to appear. Then insert the following line in your `timer()` function, so it looks like this:

```
function timer()
{
  count=count-1;
  if (count <= 0)
  {
     clearInterval(counter);
     return;
  }

 document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count + " secs"; // watch for spelling
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am having difficulty using it because my timer appears in a paragraph. How can I put the 30, 29, 28, etc. in the middle of a paragraph?

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how to display the timer in the paragraph :)

Comment: In the middle of a paragraph (horizontally) : <p id="timer" style="text-align:center"></p>

Comment: Click, your timer will only display "0 secs". You should put the innerHTML update after the decrementation, not in the end case.

Comment: Whereever you want the timer to begin, just put in the code `timer();` to call the timer function

Comment: Hi how can I stop the timer running on page load and instead only when a button is pressed? Also how can I make it reset the timer when a button is pressed after the timer has already ran down?

Comment: From: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

"**Note: To be able to use the clearInterval() method, you must use a global variable when creating the interval method**"

Comment: @Alsciende Make it more visible : <p id="timer" style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold"></p>

Answer (score 106):

I wrote this script some time ago:

Usage:

```
var myCounter = new Countdown({  
    seconds:5,  // number of seconds to count down
    onUpdateStatus: function(sec){console.log(sec);}, // callback for each second
    onCounterEnd: function(){ alert('counter ended!');} // final action
});

myCounter.start();
```

---

```
function Countdown(options) {
  var timer,
  instance = this,
  seconds = options.seconds || 10,
  updateStatus = options.onUpdateStatus || function () {},
  counterEnd = options.onCounterEnd || function () {};

  function decrementCounter() {
    updateStatus(seconds);
    if (seconds === 0) {
      counterEnd();
      instance.stop();
    }
    seconds--;
  }

  this.start = function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = 0;
    seconds = options.seconds;
    timer = setInterval(decrementCounter, 1000);
  };

  this.stop = function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
  };
}
```

Comment: I would love to use this instead of the other's. When I was stuck to restart the starting number, I see this is working nicely..

Comment: If I need to stop the timer by any chance, how do I do that?

Comment: @S.I.J 
`myCounter.stop();`

Answer (score 59):

So far the answers seem to rely on code being run instantly. If you set a timer for 1000ms, it will actually be around 1008 instead.

Here is how you should do it:

```
function timer(time,update,complete) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        var now = time-(new Date().getTime()-start);
        if( now <= 0) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            complete();
        }
        else update(Math.floor(now/1000));
    },100); // the smaller this number, the more accurate the timer will be
}
```

To use, call:

```
timer(
    5000, // milliseconds
    function(timeleft) { // called every step to update the visible countdown
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = timeleft+" second(s)";
    },
    function() { // what to do after
        alert("Timer complete!");
    }
);
```

Comment: Spot on, as you said that's the one and only way to do it right!

Comment: I gave it a thumbs up, with one caveat - _for display purposes_ you probably want to show the ceiling (Math.ceil()) instead of the floor.  It's really disorienting when the clock reaches 0 a second before the alert fires.  (Then of course there needs to be an additional call to update() before complete())

Answer (score 21):

Here is another one if anyone needs one for minutes and seconds:

```
    var mins = 10;  //Set the number of minutes you need
    var secs = mins * 60;
    var currentSeconds = 0;
    var currentMinutes = 0;
    /* 
     * The following line has been commented out due to a suggestion left in the comments. The line below it has not been tested. 
     * setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
     */
    setTimeout(Decrement,1000); 

    function Decrement() {
        currentMinutes = Math.floor(secs / 60);
        currentSeconds = secs % 60;
        if(currentSeconds <= 9) currentSeconds = "0" + currentSeconds;
        secs--;
        document.getElementById("timerText").innerHTML = currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds; //Set the element id you need the time put into.
        if(secs !== -1) setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't pass a string to the first parameter of setTimeout, `setTimeout(Decrement, 1000)` is preferred. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232574/is-it-bad-practice-to-pass-a-string-to-settimeout-if-yes-why

Answer (score 3):

```js
// Javascript Countdown
// Version 1.01 6/7/07 (1/20/2000)
// by TDavid at http://www.tdscripts.com/
var now = new Date();
var theevent = new Date("Sep 29 2007 00:00:01");
var seconds = (theevent - now) / 1000;
var minutes = seconds / 60;
var hours = minutes / 60;
var days = hours / 24;
ID = window.setTimeout("update();", 1000);

function update() {
  now = new Date();
  seconds = (theevent - now) / 1000;
  seconds = Math.round(seconds);
  minutes = seconds / 60;
  minutes = Math.round(minutes);
  hours = minutes / 60;
  hours = Math.round(hours);
  days = hours / 24;
  days = Math.round(days);
  document.form1.days.value = days;
  document.form1.hours.value = hours;
  document.form1.minutes.value = minutes;
  document.form1.seconds.value = seconds;
  ID = window.setTimeout("update();", 1000);
}
```

```html
<p><font face="Arial" size="3">Countdown To January 31, 2000, at 12:00: </font>
</p>
<form name="form1">
  <p>Days
    <input type="text" name="days" value="0" size="3">Hours
    <input type="text" name="hours" value="0" size="4">Minutes
    <input type="text" name="minutes" value="0" size="7">Seconds
    <input type="text" name="seconds" value="0" size="7">
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: This script uses very bad practices from the 90's. And also 1.5 hours is not 2 hours. It's 1 hour 30 min. You should use `Math.floor`, not `Math.round`

Answer (score 3):

**Just modified [@ClickUpvote's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1191875/6588498):**

You can use [**IIFE** (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) and recursion to make it a little bit more easier:

```
var i = 5;  //set the countdown
(function timer(){
    if (--i < 0) return;
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(i + ' secs');  //do stuff here
        timer();
    }, 1000);
})();
```

```js
var i = 5;
(function timer(){
    if (--i < 0) return;
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML = i + ' secs';
        timer();
    }, 1000);
})();
```

```html
<h1>5 secs</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding upon the accepted answer, your machine going to sleep, etc. may delay the timer from working.  You can get a true time, at the cost of a little processing.  This will give a true time left.

```
<span id="timer"></span>

<script>
var now = new Date();
var timeup = now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + 30);
//var timeup = now.setHours(now.getHours() + 1);

var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer() {
  now = new Date();
  count = Math.round((timeup - now)/1000);
  if (now > timeup) {
      window.location = "/logout"; //or somethin'
      clearInterval(counter);
      return;
  }
  var seconds = Math.floor((count%60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((count/60) % 60);
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of performances, we can now safely use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) for fast looping, instead of setInterval/setTimeout.

When using setInterval/setTimeout, if a loop task is taking more time than the interval, the browser will simply extend the interval loop, to continue the full rendering. This is creating issues. After minutes of **setInterval/setTimeout overload, this can freeze the tab, the browser or the whole computer.**

Internet devices have a wide range of performances, so it's quite impossible to hardcode a fixed interval time in milliseconds!

Using the [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), to compare the start Date Epoch and the current. This is way faster than everything else, the browser will take care of everything, at a steady **60FPS** (1000 / 60 = **16.66ms by frame**) -*[a quarter of an eye blink](https://sciencing.com/fast-blink-eye-5199669.html)*- and if the task in the loop is requiring more than that, the browser will drop some repaints.

This allow a margin before our eyes are noticing (**Human = 24FPS** => 1000 / 24 = 41.66ms by frame = fluid animation!)

https://caniuse.com/#search=requestAnimationFrame

```js
/* Seconds to (STRING)HH:MM:SS.MS ------------------------*/
/* This time format is compatible with FFMPEG ------------*/
function secToTimer(sec){
  const o = new Date(0), p =  new Date(sec * 1000)
  return new Date(p.getTime()-o.getTime()).toString().split(" ")[4] + "." + p.getMilliseconds()
}

/* Countdown loop ----------------------------------------*/
let job, origin = new Date().getTime()
const timer = () => {
  job = requestAnimationFrame(timer)
  OUT.textContent = secToTimer((new Date().getTime() - origin) / 1000)
}

/* Start looping -----------------------------------------*/
requestAnimationFrame(timer)

/* Stop looping ------------------------------------------*/
// cancelAnimationFrame(job)

/* Reset the start date ----------------------------------*/
// origin = new Date().getTime()
```

```css
span {font-size:4rem}
```

```html
<span id="OUT"></span>
<br>
<button onclick="origin = new Date().getTime()">RESET</button>
<button onclick="requestAnimationFrame(timer)">RESTART</button>
<button onclick="cancelAnimationFrame(job)">STOP</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows with pure JS. You just need to provide the function with the number of seconds and it will do the rest.

```js
var insertZero = n => n < 10 ? "0"+n : ""+n,
   displayTime = n => n ? time.textContent = insertZero(~~(n/3600)%3600) + ":" +
                                             insertZero(~~(n/60)%60) + ":" +
                                             insertZero(n%60)
                        : time.textContent = "IGNITION..!",
 countDownFrom = n => (displayTime(n), setTimeout(_ => n ? sid = countDownFrom(--n)
                                                         : displayTime(n), 1000)),
           sid;
countDownFrom(3610);
setTimeout(_ => clearTimeout(sid),20005);
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution presented by @Layton Everson I developed a counter including hours, minutes and seconds:

```
var initialSecs = 86400;
var currentSecs = initialSecs;

setTimeout(decrement,1000); 

function decrement() {
   var displayedSecs = currentSecs % 60;
   var displayedMin = Math.floor(currentSecs / 60) % 60;
   var displayedHrs = Math.floor(currentSecs / 60 /60);

    if(displayedMin <= 9) displayedMin = "0" + displayedMin;
    if(displayedSecs <= 9) displayedSecs = "0" + displayedSecs;
    currentSecs--;
    document.getElementById("timerText").innerHTML = displayedHrs + ":" + displayedMin + ":" + displayedSecs;
    if(currentSecs !== -1) setTimeout(decrement,1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Javascript Countdown
// Version 1.01 6/7/07 (1/20/2000)
// by TDavid at http://www.tdscripts.com/
var now = new Date();
var theevent = new Date("Nov 13 2017 22:05:01");
var seconds = (theevent - now) / 1000;
var minutes = seconds / 60;
var hours = minutes / 60;
var days = hours / 24;
ID = window.setTimeout("update();", 1000);

function update() {
  now = new Date();
  seconds = (theevent - now) / 1000;
  seconds = Math.round(seconds);
  minutes = seconds / 60;
  minutes = Math.round(minutes);
  hours = minutes / 60;
  hours = Math.round(hours);
  days = hours / 24;
  days = Math.round(days);
  document.form1.days.value = days;
  document.form1.hours.value = hours;
  document.form1.minutes.value = minutes;
  document.form1.seconds.value = seconds;
  ID = window.setTimeout("update();", 1000);
}
```

```html
<p><font face="Arial" size="3">Countdown To January 31, 2000, at 12:00: </font>
</p>
<form name="form1">
  <p>Days
    <input type="text" name="days" value="0" size="3">Hours
    <input type="text" name="hours" value="0" size="4">Minutes
    <input type="text" name="minutes" value="0" size="7">Seconds
    <input type="text" name="seconds" value="0" size="7">
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution works with MySQL date time formats and provides a callback function. on complition.
**Disclaimer: works only with minutes and seconds, as this is what I needed.**

```
jQuery.fn.countDownTimer = function(futureDate, callback){
    if(!futureDate){
        throw 'Invalid date!';
    }

    var currentTs = +new Date();
    var futureDateTs = +new Date(futureDate);

    if(futureDateTs <= currentTs){
        throw 'Invalid date!';
    }


    var diff = Math.round((futureDateTs - currentTs) / 1000);
    var that = this;

    (function countdownLoop(){
        // Get hours/minutes from timestamp
        var m = Math.floor(diff % 3600 / 60);
        var s = Math.floor(diff % 3600 % 60);
        var text = zeroPad(m, 2) + ':' + zeroPad(s, 2);

        $(that).text(text);

        if(diff <= 0){
            typeof callback === 'function' ? callback.call(that) : void(0);
            return;
        }

        diff--;
        setTimeout(countdownLoop, 1000);
    })();

    function zeroPad(num, places) {
      var zero = places - num.toString().length + 1;
      return Array(+(zero > 0 && zero)).join("0") + num;
    }
}

// $('.heading').countDownTimer('2018-04-02 16:00:59', function(){ // on complete})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var hr = 0;
var min = 0;
var sec = 0;
var count = 0;
var flag = false;


function start(){
    flag = true;
    stopwatch();


}
function stop(){
    flag = false;

}

function reset(){
    flag = false;
    hr = 0;
    min = 0;
    sec = 0;
    count = 0;
    document.getElementById("hr").innerHTML = "00";
    document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = "00";
    document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = "00";
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "00";

}



function stopwatch(){
    if(flag == true){
        count = count + 1;
        setTimeout( 'stopwatch()', 10);

    if(count ==100){
        count =0;
        sec = sec +1;

    }
    }

    if(sec ==60){
        min = min +1 ;
        sec = 0;

    }
      if(min == 60){
        hr = hr +1 ;
        min = 0;
        sec = 0;

    }
    var hrs = hr;
    var mins = min;
    var secs = sec;
    if(hr<10){
        hrs ="0" + hr; 

    }
    if(min<10){
        mins ="0" + min; 

    }
   if(sec<10){
        secs ="0" + sec; 

    }
    document.getElementById("hr").innerHTML = hrs;
    document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = mins;
    document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = secs;
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = count;
      
}
```