# javascript countdown timer for session timeout

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to alert the user that the session timeout is about to expire. I want to have a popup with an OK button and show the seconds ticking down on the popup. Can i do this with just java script?
Im OK with using C# code behind also.

Right now it detects session timeout and pops up telling them the session has expired.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sessionTimeout = "<%= Session.Timeout %>";

    function DisplaySessionTimeout() {
        sessionTimeout = sessionTimeout - 1;

        if (sessionTimeout >= 0)
          window.setTimeout("DisplaySessionTimeout()", 60000);
        else {
            alert("Your current Session is over due to inactivity.");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Does this script only works when the user click anything on the application or does it automatically detects the timeout like banking websites?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can do this via JavaScript. Here's a simple counter implementation [that was inspired from this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192001/196921) I found a while back:

```
function Counter(options) {
    var timer;
    var instance = this;
    var seconds = options.seconds || 10;
    var onUpdateStatus = options.onUpdateStatus || function() {};
    var onCounterEnd = options.onCounterEnd || function() {};
    var onCounterStart = options.onCounterStart || function() {};

    function decrementCounter() {
        onUpdateStatus(seconds);
        if (seconds === 0) {
            stopCounter();
            onCounterEnd();
            return;
        }
        seconds--;
    };

    function startCounter() {
        onCounterStart();
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = 0;
        decrementCounter();
        timer = setInterval(decrementCounter, 1000);
    };

    function stopCounter() {
        clearInterval(timer);
    };

    return {
        start : function() {
            startCounter();
        },
        stop : function() {
            stopCounter();
        }
    }
};
```

... and an example of how to use it:

```
var countdown = new Counter({
    // number of seconds to count down
    seconds: 3,

    onCounterStart: function () { 
        // show pop up with a message 
        ... 
    },

    // callback function for each second
    onUpdateStatus: function(second) {
        // change the UI that displays the seconds remaining in the timeout 
        ... 
    },

    // callback function for final action after countdown
    onCounterEnd: function() {
        // show message that session is over, perhaps redirect or log out 
        ... 
    }
});
countdown.start();
```

Once the server is ready to alert the user, just create the timer and it'll start counting down. You can customize what happens on each event: when timer starts, when a second ticks by, and when the countdown is done.

Answer (score 5):

I found this solution to be very helpful. You will need to set your authentication timeout in the web.config file of your project to support this but I also added the option for a user to continue their session if they would like.

add the following to your Master HTML page
in the head tag:

```
<style type="text/css">
#timeOutWarningOverlay {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 2000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

right under the start of the body tag

```
<div id="timeOutWarningOverlay">
    <div style="height:auto; width:400px; background-color:white; position: fixed;top: 50%;left: 50%; -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);transform: translate(-50%, -50%);padding:10px; text-align:center;"> 
        <div>
            <b>Your session is about to expire. Please click button below to keep this session current.</b>
            <b><span style="background-color:yellow;">00:</span><span id="time" style="background-color:yellow;">59</span></b>
        </div>
        <a id="keep" href="#">Keep Me Logged In</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the JavaScript to handle this. I like using Jquery so this is mostly in Jquery but you can get the idea from the approach. This example is for a 15 minute timeout. Remember you need to update your web.config file authentication timeout.

```
    var counter = 60;
    var idleTime = 0;
    var countdown;
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(window).click(function () {
            console.log("click has occured");
            idleTime = 0;
        })
        $(window).keyup(function () {
            console.log("key up has occured")
            idleTime = 0;
        })

        //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
        var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 60000); //found

        $('#keep').click(function () {
            idleTime = 0;
            $('#timeOutWarningOverlay').hide();
        });

    });

    function timerIncrement() {
        idleTime = idleTime + 1;
        console.log(idleTime);
        if (idleTime > 13) //13
        {
            $('#timeOutWarningOverlay').show();
            startTimer();
        }
        if (idleTime > 14) { // 14 
            window.location.href = '/login.aspx';
            alert("You session has expired due to no activity.");
        }
    };


    function startTimer() {
        countdown = setInterval(countDownClock, 1000);
    };

    function countDownClock() {
        counter = counter - 1
        if (counter < 10) {
            console.log(counter);
            $('#time').text("0" + counter);
        }
        else {
            console.log(counter);
            $('#time').text(counter);
        }
        if (counter == 0) {
            counter = 60;
            clearInterval(countdown);
            console.log(counter);
            console.log("done");
        }
    };
```

The message will pop up after 14 minutes and start to count down the seconds for the user. Hope this helps, happy coding.

Comment: Really helpful... Made my day easy. I've added the cursor moving function as well. works great. thanks for the idea. cheers!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using setInterval instead of setTimeout.

Something like this:

```
<script>
var startTime = new Date(milliseconds),
    timeoutLength = 60000;

var interval = setInterval("checkTimeout()",1000);
function checkTimeout() {
    var currentTime = new Date(millisecond);
    if (currentTime > startTime + timeoutLength) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        alert ("Your current Session is over due to inactivity.");
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do i need to call this function from page load to get it to fire? If so, how?

Comment: Could you please add a little bit of information about where to add this and how exactly this works. `milliseconds` throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 -  Count down Timer**

*First just simple make countdown timer , code is given below and if you done then simple add windows.location path (redirect page address) .*

```
 <sctipt>
        var interval;
         $(document).on('mousemove', function () {
             clearInterval(interval);
             var coutdown = 5 * 60, $timer = $('.timer'); // After 5 minutes session expired  (mouse button click code)
             $timer.text(coutdown);
             interval = setInterval(function () {
                 $timer.text(--coutdown);

                 if (coutdown === 0) {

                     alert("Session expired User successfully logout.");
                     window.location = "UserLogin.aspx";
                 }

             }, 1000);
         }).mousemove();



         var interval;
                     $(document).on('keydown', function () {
             clearInterval(interval);
             var coutdown = 5 * 60, $timer = $('.timer'); // After 5 minutes session expired (keyboard button press code)
             $timer.text(coutdown);
             interval = setInterval(function () {
                 $timer.text(--coutdown);

                 if (coutdown === 0) {

                     alert("Session expired User successfully logout.");
                     window.location = "UserLogin.aspx";
                 }

             }, 1000);
         }).mousemove();
    <sctipt>
```

*And if you want show the time on your web page add this code .*

```
   <html>
         <div class="timer">     
          <p> Session Time</p> 
         </div>
    </html>
```

**Solution 2 -  Count down Timer with buttons**

> HTML :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <div class="timer">
            <span class="hour">00</span>:<span class="minute">00</span>:<span class="second">10</span>
        </div>
        <div class="control">
            <button onClick="timer.start(1000)">Start</button> 
            <button onClick="timer.stop()">Stop</button> 
            <button onClick="timer.reset(60)">Reset</button> 
            <button onClick="timer.mode(1)">Count up</button> 
            <button onClick="timer.mode(0)">Count down</button>
        </div>
```

> CSS :

```
div.timer {
    border:1px #666666 solid;
    width:190px;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    font-size:36px;
    font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    text-align:center;
    margin:5px;
}
```

> Javascript:

```
function _timer(callback)
{
    var time = 0;     //  The default time of the timer
    var mode = 1;     //    Mode: count up or count down
    var status = 0;    //    Status: timer is running or stoped
    var timer_id;    //    This is used by setInterval function

    // this will start the timer ex. start the timer with 1 second interval timer.start(1000) 
    this.start = function(interval)
    {
        interval = (typeof(interval) !== 'undefined') ? interval : 1000;

        if(status == 0)
        {
            status = 1;
            timer_id = setInterval(function()
            {
                switch(mode)
                {
                    default:
                    if(time)
                    {
                        time--;
                        generateTime();
                        if(typeof(callback) === 'function') callback(time);
                    }
                    break;

                    case 1:
                    if(time < 86400)
                    {
                        time++;
                        generateTime();
                        if(typeof(callback) === 'function') callback(time);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }, interval);
        }
    }

    //  Same as the name, this will stop or pause the timer ex. timer.stop()
    this.stop =  function()
    {
        if(status == 1)
        {
            status = 0;
            clearInterval(timer_id);
        }
    }

    // Reset the timer to zero or reset it to your own custom time ex. reset to zero second timer.reset(0)
    this.reset =  function(sec)
    {
        sec = (typeof(sec) !== 'undefined') ? sec : 0;
        time = sec;
        generateTime(time);
    }

    // Change the mode of the timer, count-up (1) or countdown (0)
    this.mode = function(tmode)
    {
        mode = tmode;
    }

    // This methode return the current value of the timer
    this.getTime = function()
    {
        return time;
    }

    // This methode return the current mode of the timer count-up (1) or countdown (0)
    this.getMode = function()
    {
        return mode;
    }

    // This methode return the status of the timer running (1) or stoped (1)
    this.getStatus
    {
        return status;
    }

    // This methode will render the time variable to hour:minute:second format
    function generateTime()
    {
        var second = time % 60;
        var minute = Math.floor(time / 60) % 60;
        var hour = Math.floor(time / 3600) % 60;

        second = (second < 10) ? '0'+second : second;
        minute = (minute < 10) ? '0'+minute : minute;
        hour = (hour < 10) ? '0'+hour : hour;

        $('div.timer span.second').html(second);
        $('div.timer span.minute').html(minute);
        $('div.timer span.hour').html(hour);
    }
}

// example use
var timer;

$(document).ready(function(e) 
{
    timer = new _timer
    (
        function(time)
        {
            if(time == 0)
            {
                timer.stop();
                alert('time out');
            }
        }
    );
    timer.reset(0);
    timer.mode(0);
});
```

Comment: please try to be more descriptive in your explanation