# Can i make a number appear on my page then have it increase by x every z seconds

Tags: php, javascript, html

Take this number `"#1"`
Make it turn to a `"#2"` in `5 seconds`
Then to a `"#3"` in `5 seconds`

Is this possible, or how do i accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, you can do that in javascript quite easily. You should google for *javascript countdown timer*, there will be plenty of tutorials and you will learn some javascript code while doing it. Much better than just hoping someone will post a working script.

Comment: yes its possible, tried anything?

Comment: This has been answered before on Stack Overflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191865/code-for-a-simple-javascript-countdown-timer

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/LXZy8/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because PHP executes on the server and only sends the resulting output to the browser, we can't use only PHP to update it.

Easiest method would be to use JavaScript's [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) method.

```
function update() {
  var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
  counter.innerText = counter.innerText*1 + 1;
  setTimeout(update, 1000);
} 

<body onload="update()">
  <div id="counter">0</div>
</body>
```

The update function gets called once on the body's load and then it calls itself after 1000ms to make a 1 second counter. Note: I have to multiply the `innerText` by 1 to convert a string to a number so it will add instead of concatenating.

Another way of doing this, although I don't know why you'd want to do it this way (but it uses PHP.. lol) is to refresh the page with an updated query string parameter.

```
<?PHP
$newcount = 0;
if(isset($_GET['count'])) {
    $newcount = $_GET['count'] + 1;
    echo $newcount;
}

echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=\"1;URL='a.php?count={$newcount}'\">";
?>
```

Here I get the current value of the counter and add 1 using PHP and then echo a [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) tag to, after 1 second, refresh the page with the updated count value in the query string. Next time the page loads, it'll read that value, add one, refresh with the new value, etc. This is just to show you another way, I would **not** recommend doing this in your application!

Comment: Anyone who uses the second version in a real-world scenario deserves to be beaten to death!  Just because you CAN do something does NOT make it a good idea!

Comment: Ohh ok thank you lots. i got `<head>
<span id="timer"></span>
</head>

<body>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
var count=30;

var counter=setInterval("timer()",1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second


function timer()
{
  count=count+1;
  if (count <= 0)
  {
     clearInterval(counter);
     return;
  }

 document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count + " secs";
}
</script>
</body>
`
for ne one else who needs the quick code

Comment: @XavierD: Please don't actually pass strings to `setInterval`.  it uses `eval`.  Pass functions instead.  `setInterval(timer, 1000);` or `setInterval(function(){ timer(); },1000);`