# Javascript: Countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could somebody tell me how to make a countdown timer in Javascript or JQuery where:

When the timer hits 21:00:00 (h:m:s) it resets itself and starts counting from 23:59:59.
And this repeats itself everyday.

Comment: What have you tried?  What are you having trouble with?  What code have you found that you can't use?  We are here to help, not do it for you.

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191865/code-for-a-simple-javascript-countdown-timer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  As these two gents have already hinted at, showing the effort you've put in so far in the form of code will show the community that you are putting in the effort worthy of an answer, as well as allows us to help you more easily

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search gives me a link to some simple countdown script here http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

But anything like to loop your countdown back to 23:59:59 would need some more study into the code itself I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can check some JQuery timers here: 
http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/11/jquery-countdown-scripts.html