# Css animation lifetime

Tags: css, webkit, css-animations

I can't understand how to run animation for some constant period of time.

Here is the source of animation:

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.pulse {
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
}
```

So I modify css of the element where I want apply `pulse`.

```
-webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 10;
```

As I understand docs, the animation should be run 10 times for 10s each. So, 100 seconds at all. But this is wrong. What is the right way to specify animation life as 100 seconds?

Comment: How you count *5100 seconds*?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RJkbS/1/ ??

Comment: @Mr.Alien Sorry, that was a mistake. `100` is the right number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so you say that the timing function you are getting is incorrect, well I won't agree to that, when you are setting an animation duration to `10s` that means, 5s for first cycle, and in the next 5s for your `div` to scale out.

I am using JavaScript count down here, and am also using `animation-delay` property set to 1 seconds, just to sync with JavaScript countdown which I took from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1191875/1542290)...

So if you see, the animation ends perfectly at `1` so it works perfectly, if you are expecting to do something else than please comment and I will modify my answer accordingly..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RJkbS/2/) *(I've reduced the animation iteration to 2 = 20 seconds)*

> Note: Use **Chrome** to see the Demo as OP is using only `-webkit` and
>   haven't requested any code for Firefox or Internet Explorer.

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(2);
        transform: scale(2);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

.pulse {
    -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 2;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 50px;
    top: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Great answer. I think there is some mistake in my code. Will rewrite it refer to your answer. Thank you.