# Creating Countdown with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a countdown that runs daily from 8am to 8pm Monday-Friday and 8am-6pm Saturday and Sunday and then when it's finished, says something like 'We open tomorrow at 8am!'

How can I achieve this?

Website: (you can see where the countdown would be.)

http://www.securemyhome.com/test-pulse3

HTML

```
 <div class="wereOpen"><span class="blue">We'll Call You!</span><br />Only 
 <span class="countdown">
 <!--  COUNTDOWN BANNER  -->
        7 hours 
        35 minutes 
</span> left!</div>
```

Here's a few i've tried.

```
var count=30;

var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

function timer()
{
count=count-1;
if (count <= 0)
{
 clearInterval(counter);
 //counter ended, do something here
 return;
 }

 //Do code for showing the number of seconds here
 }
```

## 2

```
 function Countdown(options) {
  var timer,
 instance = this,
   seconds = options.seconds || 10,
 updateStatus = options.onUpdateStatus || function () {},
 counterEnd = options.onCounterEnd || function () {};

 function decrementCounter() {
 updateStatus(seconds);
 if (seconds === 0) {
  counterEnd();
  instance.stop();
   }
   seconds--;
  }

  this.start = function () {
  clearInterval(timer);
   timer = 0;
  seconds = options.seconds;
  timer = setInterval(decrementCounter, 1000);
  };

  this.stop = function () {
   clearInterval(timer);
  };
 }
```

Comment: *"anything else needed"* ... yes, some kind of attempt.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are plenty of countdown plugins out there if you want a pre-made solution.

Comment: If you have so litte knowledge in JS that you can't even *attempt* anything, you probably shouldn't turn to this site for help.

Comment: I have tried a few but I can't find any that are set to daily times like 8am-8pm M-F and 8am-6pm S-S. Most countdowns seem to be to a specific date and do not restart daily.

Comment: You're going to need to increase your knowledge of java script if you expect to do something like this.  Even if someone spends the time to write a method for you, how will you support it if you don't understand it?

Comment: I can do basic functions of Javascript, like if you scroll down on the site you'll see how the header bar changes. However, I do not have enough knowledge to create whatever I need. (If that makes sense)

Comment: That is why Rick said you should increase your knowledge of javascript. SO isn't designed for people to just write your code for you, when you haven't shown any effort.

Comment: @forgivenson I have messed with three or so Javascript and jQuery codes, but I can't seem to get it to be a daily thing

Comment: Then post what you have tried, with a specific question about where you are having an issue.

Comment: @forgivenson, I have.

Comment: @Emissary I posted the scripts to my first two attempts at it, I wouldn't have asked here if I hadn't already attempted for two days.

Comment: You've done sod all - [example 1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1191875/1238344) and [example 2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1192001/1238344) have been blatantly copied from the same question and don't even remotely correlate to your HTML - we are not stupid and we are not amused.

Comment: @Emissary, those are the scripts I had previously taken and tried to implement into my site. Obviously, I had changed the codes to correlate with mine.

Comment: Look the bottom line is Stack is a site for learning - it doesn't matter if it doesn't work - the point is that if you explain what **YOU** have tried and what errors you encounter people will be more inclined to help you understand where and why you are going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since everyone is ripping you apart and being of no help, here's a code that is similar to what you may want. Adjust accordingly.

```
// 24 hour based
var targetHour = 10;

var currentTime = new Date();

// sun 0 mon 1 ... fri 5 sat 6
var currentDay = currentTime.getDay();

var offset = 24;
                // friday
if (currentDay === 5) {
    offset = 60;
}              // saturday
else if(currentDay === 6) {                                                                   
    offset = 48;
}

if(currentTime.getHours() > targetHour) {
    console.log('hours:', (targetHour + offset) - currentTime.getHours() - 1);
    console.log('minutes:', 60 - currentTime.getMinutes());
} 
else if(currentTime.getHours() < targetHour) {
    console.log(targetHour - currentTime.getHours() - 1);
    console.log('minutes:', 60 - currentTime.getMinutes());
}
```

Comment: No one is ripping anyone, these are the rules of Stack Overflow - blatant code requests are no benefit to anyone but self-serving posters who have no interest in learning and only serve to perpetuate a cycle that is polluting the site and diluting it's quality as a learning resource.