# Countdown timer is not running

Tags: javascript, countdown

OK thanks all. The problem is solved after i see comment.

My countdown timer is not running.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function timer(){
var count = document.getElementById("numb").value;
var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000);
var detik = count;
    do {
        count--;
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count + " secs";
        if (count<=0) {
            count = detik+1;
        }
    } while (count===detik+1);
}

</script>

<input type="text" id="numb" name="numb" value=""></input>
<input type="button" value="click" onClick="timer();"/>
<span id="timer"></span>
```

Comment: Related: Never use `setInterval` to manually take 1 away from `i` every 1 second because you think it will be executed exactly every second, but the reality is, it won't.

Comment: Not really hard to find a good example :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191865/code-for-a-simple-javascript-countdown-timer

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2J9gg/

Comment: @user3142044: check my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

There were some logic problem with your timer function. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LdvDE/20/).

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="url" name="url" value=""></input>
<input type="button" value="click" onClick="timer();" />
<span id="timer"></span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 function timer() {
clearInterval(counter);
var count = parseInt(document.getElementById("url").value);
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = count + " secs";
var counter = setInterval(function () {
    count = count - 1;
    if (count <= 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = count + " secs";
}, 1000);
```

};

Answer (score 0):

There is a `logical error` in your code. Say, you gave `5` as input and clicked the button.
The `count` stores `5` and so is `detik`.

Inside the `do-while` loop, the count is decremented,(now `4`). Then this is being displayed to the screen. The `if` condition isn't satisfied. But the `do-while` condition is also not true. Hence it comes out of the loop.

This whole process repeats again since you have `setInterval` for the function. On the whole you see the counter remaining the same.

What you need to do is this:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="numb" name="numb" value=""></input>
<input type="button" value="click" onClick="start_timer();"/>
<span id="timer"></span>
```

**JS:**

```
var count;
var intrv;
function start_timer(){
    count = document.getElementById("numb").value;
    count = parseInt(count);//convert to int..
    intrv = setInterval(timer, 1000);
}
function timer(){
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = count + " secs";
    count--;
    if(count<0)
    {
        clearInterval(intrv);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var count = 0;
var inter;
function timer1(flag){
    if(flag == 1)
    {
        count = document.getElementById("url").value;
        console.log(count);
        flag = 0;
    }
    count--;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML= count + " secs";
    if(count<=0){
        clearTimeout(inter);
    }else{
        inter = setTimeout(function(){timer1(0)},1000);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="url" name="url" value="">
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="timer1(1);"/>
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I changed it like this and it works:

```
window.timer = function timer() {
    var count = document.getElementById("numb").value;
    var cTimer = document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML;

    if(cTimer && !isNaN(parseInt(cTimer))) cTimer = parseInt(cTimer) - 1;
    else cTimer = count;
    if(cTimer==0) return;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = cTimer + " secs";
    setTimeout(timer, 1000);
}
```

and this your working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KG7LG/1/).

Comment: no, i don't mean it. the value must input not parameter.<input type="text" id="url" name="url" value=""></input>
<input type="button" value="click" onClick="timer(url);"/>

Comment: @user3142044: check my answer again.