# clear setinterval on mouseover and resume on mouse out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am trying to modify some existing code and can't get it working correctly.  When the mouse is over div id "mine" I need the setinterval to stop and when the mouse is not over the div for the set interval to resume.  I've tried and tried all day and night to get this working and just don't seem to be able to do it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

// check all
jQuery(this).on('click', '#selectall', function() {
  jQuery('.checkbox').prop('checked', jQuery(this).is(":checked"));
});

    // ajax
    jQuery(this).on('submit', 'form[name="dispatchform"]', function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: jQuery(this).attr('action'),
            data: jQuery(this).serialize(),
            type: 'post',
            beforeSend: function(){jQuery('body').css('opacity', '0.5');},
            success: function(data) {
                var response = jQuery(data).find('#dispatchTable').html();
                jQuery('#dispatchTable').html(response);

                //message
                var msg = jQuery(data).find('td.messageStackError, td.messageStackSuccess').html();
                jQuery('#msg').css({
                    'padding': '10px',
                    'text-align': 'center',
                    'font-size': '12px',
                    'background-color': 'darkkhaki',
                    'margin': '10px 0',
                    'color': '#fff'
                }).html(msg);
            },
            complete: function(){jQuery('body').css('opacity', '1');}
        });
        return false;
    });


          setInterval(function() {
      jQuery.ajax({
            url: jQuery(this).attr('action'),
            data: jQuery(this).serialize(),
            type: 'post',
            beforeSend: function(){jQuery('body').css('opacity', '0.5');},
            success: function(data) {
                var response = jQuery(data).find('#dispatchTable').html();
                jQuery('#dispatchTable').html(response);

                //message
                var msg = jQuery(data).find('td.messageStackError, td.messageStackSuccess').html();
                if(msg !== undefined) {
                jQuery('#msg').css({
                    'padding': '10px',
                    'text-align': 'center',
                    'font-size': '12px',
                    'background-color': 'darkkhaki',
                    'margin': '10px 0',
                    'color': '#fff'
                }).html(msg);
                }
            },
            complete: function(){jQuery('body').css('opacity', '1');}
        });
    }, 15000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where, exactly you want that to happen...

What I mean is that I don't see `div#mine` anywhere in that code, so I don't know if it's supposed to be inside of one of those, or outside of all of them, or both outside, and also inside, if under special circumstances...

...regardless, the general idea is the following:

```
var doSomethingId;

function doSomething ( ) { }

var mine = document.querySelector("#mine");
mine.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
    doSomething();
    doSomethingId = setInterval(doSomething, 10000);
});

mine.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
    clearInterval(doSomethingId);
});
```

There's not a whole lot more to it than that.  The jQuery also isn't much smaller.

The key is to save the ID (`var id = setInterval(/*...*/);`) and use it to clear the interval (`clearInterval(id);`).
You don't "restart" the interval; rather, you call `id = setInterval(...);` again, so that the id is now the new interval, so you can stop the new interval.

#### Edit:

This is really an "XY" problem...
That is to say that you're looking for a solution to a problem that isn't really at the root of your problems, but rather a problem that is an offshoot, on top of the root.

A quick example:
most forms, I fill out by tabbing into, tabbing through the fields, and then either hitting ENTER, or tabbing down to the submit button and hitting ENTER

In this case (people who use keyboards/touchscreens/etc), you're still going to have the problem you're facing, now.

That said, if you're willing to refactor a little, the solution can be the same.

What I mean is, instead of your `setInterval(function () { jQuery./*...*/ });

What you want to do is something like;

```
var shouldUpdate = true,
    form  = this,
    $mine = jQuery("#mine");

$mine.on("mouseover", function () { shouldUpdate = false; });
$mine.on("mouseout",  function () { shouldUpdate = true;  });

// whole setInterval(function () { jQuery.ajax(...); }); copied and pasted here, plus the `if`
function submitForm () {
    if (!shouldUpdate) { return; }
    jQuery.ajax(/* ... */);
}

var submitId = setInterval(submitForm, 15000);
// clearInterval(submitId); -- just remember to set the new ID, if you restart it
```

As you can see, I don't really need the interval to be started and stopped, now.
I've got an `if` that returns if I'm in any state that I shouldn't be updating in
(really, this should go one step further, and abort any XHR calls that are already happening, if you do start editing a field).

Comment: so I would add the above content from `set interval(){jquery.ajax({` right after your `doSomethingId = ` the replacing your `setInterval(doSomething, 10000);` with the original code that starts with `set interval(){jquery.ajax({`  @norguard

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish with that old code, or where your `mouseover` goes...  ...the old code is setting itself up to listen for things to happen on the page...  so wrapping it would just make it wait for `mouseover` before listening for things to happen...  ...maybe that's what you want.  I don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This is a form that updates every 20 seconds with new information from a database.  Unfortunately we also have to enter information into the form and click submit.  We keep running into the problem that while trying to enter information into the form and click submit the form updates causing us to start all over again.  So I want the page to update as coded now every 20 seconds when the mouse  is not over the 'div#mine` when the mouse is over the `div#mine` I want the form to stop updating.  So where would I insert the existing code into the function to accomplish this?  Thank you!!

Comment: @David Have a look at the edit. Hopefully, you can see where the `mouseover` isn't going to be 100% of your solution.

Comment: I will give this a whirl.  It looks like you have a great solution.  This form is a dropdown list followed by checkboxes and a submit button.  So tabbing/keyboard really isn't the issue and I don't have a touch screen.  Your solution looks like it is ideal if I can get it coded properly.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Been trying for days to get this going.  Here is my latest attempt that doesn't work.  Can someone please help me out. It's too long to post in one comment so I will make two more with the remaining code.   `<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?php echo CHARSET; ?>">
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$( "#mine" )
.mouseout(function() {
var submitId = setInterval(submitForm, 5000);
})
.mouseover(function() {
disableCounter();
`// check all
jQuery(this).on('click', '#selectall', function() {
jQuery('.checkbox').prop('checked',`

Comment: ` jQuery(this).is(":checked"));
});
// ajax
jQuery(this).on('submit', 'form[name="dispatchform"]', function(){
jQuery.ajax({url: jQuery(this).attr('action'),
data: jQuery(this).serialize(),
type: 'post',
beforeSend: function(){jQuery('body').css('opacity', '0.5');},
success: function(data) {var response =jQuery(data).find('#dispatchTable').html();
jQuery('#dispatchTable').html(response);
//message
var msg = jQuery(data).find('td.messageStackError, td.messageStackSuccess').html();
jQuery('#msg').css({
'padding': '10px',
'text-align': 'center',
`

Comment: `'font-size': '12px',
'background-color': 'darkkhaki',
'margin': '10px 0',
'color': '#fff'                       }).html(msg);
},
complete: function(){jQuery('body').css('opacity', '1');}
});
return false;
});
});
function init(){
cssjsmenu('navbar');
if (document.getElementById){
var kill = document.getElementById('hoverJS');
kill.disabled = true;
}
}
});
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="init()">
<p>no update area</p>
<div id="mine">
<form></form></div>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191865/code-for-a-simple-javascript-countdown-timer) I guess you'd like to accomplish something like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#mine{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
</style>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Counter:</p>
<div id="mine"></div>
<div id="counter">
</div>

<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#mine" )
    .mouseout(function() {
        enableCounter();
    })
    .mouseover(function() {
        disableCounter();
    });
});

var count=10;
var counterEnabled = true;
var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); //run every 1 second

function timer(){
  if (counterEnabled)
    count--;

  if (count == 0){
     alert('execute submit here!');
     count = 10;
  }

  $('#counter').text(count);
}

function enableCounter(){
    counterEnabled = true;
}
function disableCounter(){
    counterEnabled = false;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Been trying for days to get this going.  Here is my latest attempt that doesn't work.  Can someone please help me out.