# Keypress Event - Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, keypress, countdowntimer

I want to start a timer at first keypress (on the ) and it should count down till 0. The catch is that once it is started it should not stop until it has reached 0 nor it should be affected by subsequent key presses.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Should it countdown in seconds?  How should the timer be presented?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191865/code-for-a-simple-javascript-countdown-timer

Comment: I'd also suggest not posting "Can anyone help me out asap".  The "asap" is likely to be read badly by potential responders.

Comment: yes, it should be in seconds. My problem is not the timer but to start the timer at a key press and it should not be affected by the subsequent key presses

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 align="center"></h1>
<script>
 var time=10;
 var timer;
    $('body').keypress(function() {
        timer=setInterval(function(){
            if(time<=0)
                clearInterval(timer);
            $('h1').html(time);
            time--;
        },1000)
        $(this).unbind('keypress');
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. But I don't want a button to start the timer. I want the timer to be started when a key is pressed (any one key) and it should not be affected by the subsequent key presses.

Comment: i changed code now it starts when key pressed

Comment: it does but your timer gets affected by the subsequent key presses.   Is there any way to apply the concept of threads in js/jquery? With the help of threads we may be able to achieve what my problem statement states.

Comment: correct again now subsequent key presses doesn't affect