# Create a simple 10 second countdown

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I would like a line that says:

`Your download will begin in (10, 9, 8, etc. Beginning on page load) seconds.`

I already have the 10 second download text set up, and I have looked at other stackoverflow posts. They all include CSS, and Jquery. I would like just a Javascript/HTML timer.

No other requests have been made for a simple line stating "You're download will begin in x seconds". How would I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code for a simple JavaScript countdown timer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191865/code-for-a-simple-javascript-countdown-timer)

Comment: JavaScript timer functions all work in milliseconds, so you are going to have to work in milliseconds at some point in time in your code.

Comment: If you used the code in the answer below, then you used milliseconds in the `},1000);` line.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

JavaScript has built in to it a function called `setInterval`, which takes two arguments - a function, `callback` and an integer, `timeout`. When called, `setInterval` will call the function you give it every `timeout` milliseconds.

For example, if you wanted to make an alert window every 500 milliseconds, you could do something like this.

```
function makeAlert(){ 
    alert("Popup window!");
};

setInterval(makeAlert, 500);
```

However, you don't have to name your function or declare it separately. Instead, you could define your function inline, like this.

```
setInterval(function(){ alert("Popup window!"); }, 500);
```

Once `setInterval` is called, it will run until you call `clearInterval` on the return value. This means that the previous example would just run infinitely. We can put all of this information together to make a progress bar that will update every second and after 10 seconds, stop updating.

```js
var timeleft = 10;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
  if(timeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
  }
  document.getElementById("progressBar").value = 10 - timeleft;
  timeleft -= 1;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<progress value="0" max="10" id="progressBar"></progress>
```

Alternatively, this will create a text countdown.

```js
var timeleft = 10;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
  if(timeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Finished";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + " seconds remaining";
  }
  timeleft -= 1;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution. To make the progress smoother you can of course reduce the timer (e.g. from 1000 to 100) and increase the time (e.g. from 10 to 100).

Answer (score 68):

This does it in text.

```html
<p> The download will begin in <span id="countdowntimer">10 </span> Seconds</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var timeleft = 10;
    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
    timeleft--;
    document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
    if(timeleft <= 0)
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    },1000);
</script>
```

Comment: How Can I make it loop all the time??

Comment: @GonzaloPani Wrap the code in a `setInterval`

Answer (score 13):

A solution using Promises, includes both progress bar & text countdown.

```js
ProgressCountdown(10, 'pageBeginCountdown', 'pageBeginCountdownText').then(value => alert(`Page has started: ${value}.`));

function ProgressCountdown(timeleft, bar, text) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var countdownTimer = setInterval(() => {
      timeleft--;

      document.getElementById(bar).value = timeleft;
      document.getElementById(text).textContent = timeleft;

      if (timeleft <= 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        resolve(true);
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="row begin-countdown">
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <progress value="10" max="10" id="pageBeginCountdown"></progress>
    <p> Begining in <span id="pageBeginCountdownText">10 </span> seconds</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: working fine. but I want to keep the page refreshed. don't restart.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      ProgressCountdown(10, "pageBeginCountdownText");

      function ProgressCountdown(timeleft, text) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          var countdownTimer = setInterval(() => {
            timeleft--;

            document.getElementById(text).textContent = timeleft;

            if (timeleft <= 0) {
              clearInterval(countdownTimer);
              resolve(true);
            }
          }, 1000);
        });
      }
    </script>

    <style>
      .dot {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .clock {
        text-align: center;
      }
      .pp {
        text-align: center;
      }

      
    </style>

    <div class="row begin-countdown">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <div class="dot" style="position: center">
          <h3 id="pageBeginCountdownText" class="clock">10</h3>
          <p class="pp">Seonds</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var seconds_inputs =  document.getElementsByClassName('deal_left_seconds');
    var total_timers = seconds_inputs.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < total_timers; i++){
        var str_seconds = 'seconds_'; var str_seconds_prod_id = 'seconds_prod_id_';
        var seconds_prod_id = seconds_inputs[i].getAttribute('data-value');
        var cal_seconds = seconds_inputs[i].getAttribute('value');

        eval('var ' + str_seconds + seconds_prod_id + '= ' + cal_seconds + ';');
        eval('var ' + str_seconds_prod_id + seconds_prod_id + '= ' + seconds_prod_id + ';');
    }
    function timer() {
        for ( var i = 0; i < total_timers; i++) {
            var seconds_prod_id = seconds_inputs[i].getAttribute('data-value');

            var days = Math.floor(eval('seconds_'+seconds_prod_id) / 24 / 60 / 60);
            var hoursLeft = Math.floor((eval('seconds_'+seconds_prod_id)) - (days * 86400));
            var hours = Math.floor(hoursLeft / 3600);
            var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours * 3600));
            var minutes = Math.floor(minutesLeft / 60);
            var remainingSeconds = eval('seconds_'+seconds_prod_id) % 60;

            function pad(n) {
                return (n < 10 ? "0" + n : n);
            }
            document.getElementById('deal_days_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = pad(days);
            document.getElementById('deal_hrs_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = pad(hours);
            document.getElementById('deal_min_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = pad(minutes);
            document.getElementById('deal_sec_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = pad(remainingSeconds);

            if (eval('seconds_'+ seconds_prod_id) == 0) {
                clearInterval(countdownTimer);
                document.getElementById('deal_days_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = document.getElementById('deal_hrs_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = document.getElementById('deal_min_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = document.getElementById('deal_sec_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = pad(0);
            } else {
                var value = eval('seconds_'+seconds_prod_id);
                value--;
                eval('seconds_' + seconds_prod_id + '= ' + value + ';');
            }
        }
    }

    var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" class="deal_left_seconds" data-value="1" value="10">
<div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="date box"> <span class="key" id="deal_days_1">00</span> <span class="value">DAYS</span> </div>
</div>
<div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="hour box"> <span class="key" id="deal_hrs_1">00</span> <span class="value">HRS</span> </div>
</div>
<div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="minutes box"> <span class="key" id="deal_min_1">00</span> <span class="value">MINS</span> </div>
</div>
<div class="box-wrapper hidden-md">
    <div class="seconds box"> <span class="key" id="deal_sec_1">00</span> <span class="value">SEC</span> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

```js
var seconds_inputs =  document.getElementsByClassName('deal_left_seconds');
    var total_timers = seconds_inputs.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < total_timers; i++){
        var str_seconds = 'seconds_'; var str_seconds_prod_id = 'seconds_prod_id_';
        var seconds_prod_id = seconds_inputs[i].getAttribute('data-value');
        var cal_seconds = seconds_inputs[i].getAttribute('value');

        eval('var ' + str_seconds + seconds_prod_id + '= ' + cal_seconds + ';');
        eval('var ' + str_seconds_prod_id + seconds_prod_id + '= ' + seconds_prod_id + ';');
    }
    function timer() {
        for ( var i = 0; i < total_timers; i++) {
            var seconds_prod_id = seconds_inputs[i].getAttribute('data-value');

            var days = Math.floor(eval('seconds_'+seconds_prod_id) / 24 / 60 / 60);
            var hoursLeft = Math.floor((eval('seconds_'+seconds_prod_id)) - (days * 86400));
            var hours = Math.floor(hoursLeft / 3600);
            var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours * 3600));
            var minutes = Math.floor(minutesLeft / 60);
            var remainingSeconds = eval('seconds_'+seconds_prod_id) % 60;

            function pad(n) {
                return (n < 10 ? "0" + n : n);
            }
            document.getElementById('deal_days_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = pad(days);
            document.getElementById('deal_hrs_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = pad(hours);
            document.getElementById('deal_min_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = pad(minutes);
            document.getElementById('deal_sec_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = pad(remainingSeconds);

            if (eval('seconds_'+ seconds_prod_id) == 0) {
                clearInterval(countdownTimer);
                document.getElementById('deal_days_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = document.getElementById('deal_hrs_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = document.getElementById('deal_min_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = document.getElementById('deal_sec_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = pad(0);
            } else {
                var value = eval('seconds_'+seconds_prod_id);
                value--;
                eval('seconds_' + seconds_prod_id + '= ' + value + ';');
            }
        }
    }

    var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" class="deal_left_seconds" data-value="1" value="10">
<div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="date box"> <span class="key" id="deal_days_1">00</span> <span class="value">DAYS</span> </div>
</div>
<div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="hour box"> <span class="key" id="deal_hrs_1">00</span> <span class="value">HRS</span> </div>
</div>
<div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="minutes box"> <span class="key" id="deal_min_1">00</span> <span class="value">MINS</span> </div>
</div>
<div class="box-wrapper hidden-md">
    <div class="seconds box"> <span class="key" id="deal_sec_1">0p0</span> <span class="value">SEC</span> </div>
</div>
```