# HTML Javascript redirect after countdown

Tags: javascript, html

using the code form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106189/create-a-simple-10-second-countdown) how could I redirect the page after the countdown ends?

`var timeleft = 10;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
  if(timeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Finished";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + " seconds remaining";
  }
  timeleft -= 1;
}, 1000);
<div id="countdown"></div>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var timeleft = 10;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
  if(timeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Finished";
    window.location.href = "Path to html redirect file here";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + " seconds remaining";
  }
  timeleft -= 1;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Basically just add window.location.href = "Path to html redirect file here"; to the if statement and add the path that you want to redirect to.

Answer (score 1):

just add a location.replace() in your if statement

```js
var timeleft = 10;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
  if(timeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Finished";
    location.replace("https://www.stackoverflow.com")
  } else {
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + " seconds remaining";
  }
  timeleft -= 1;
  
  
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just use `window.location` method**

Update your Javascript code to this

```
if(timeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Finished";
    //the complete URL where you want to redirect
    window.location = "https://www.exapmle.com/"
} else {
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + " seconds remaining";
}
```

Comment: Windows.location is NOT a helper :/

Answer (score 0):

You can do a redirect by assigning to `window.location.href`.

```js
let timeleft = 10;
const downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
  if (timeleft <= 0) {
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Finished";
    window.location.href = 'https://www.youtube.com/dQw4w9WgXcQ';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + " seconds remaining";
  }
  timeleft -= 1;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```