# Object undefined- Javascript Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've modified [this existing countdown timer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192001/3629765) so that I can run multiple countdown and used session to display the timer in HTML. The `runCountdown` function now looks like this:

```
runCountdown(object, param, sessionName)
```

`object` is used instead of `var myCounter` of the solution. `param` is for countdown seconds. `sessionName` is for storing count current second to show it in the browser dynamically.

Now I want to run several countdown timer simultaneously , thus in the Meteor app I've done something like this

```
Meteor.call('doCount', function(error, result) {
  if ( !result < 1 ) {
    counters = new Array(result);
    var queryResult = ProductList.find().fetch();

    for (i = 0; i < counters.length; i++) {
      var diff = queryResult[i].expire - Math.floor(TimeSync.serverTime() / 1000);
      runCountdown(counters[i], diff, queryResult[i]._id);
    }
    console.log('testing from doCount ' + counters[0]);
  }
});
```

`doCount` returns the number of Countdown Timers I want to run in the browser.

Now the weird thing is that my `runCountdown` function inside the for loop is working properly as I can see from the browser console, which implies that `counters` variable is being used this function. Obviously my main objective is not to log the object but it's showing `undefined`.
Why is that happening?

**The `runCountdown` function**

```
function runCountdown(obj,param,sessionName){
    obj = new Countdown({
        seconds:param,  // number of seconds to count down
        onUpdateStatus:
            function(sec){
                Session.set(sessionName,sec);
                console.log(Session.get(sessionName));
            }, // callback for each second
        onCounterEnd: function(){ alert('counter ended!');} // final action
    });

    obj.start();

}
```

Comment: probably you are using javascript in strict mode which doesn't allow defining global variable.

Comment: I'm not sure what  Javascript strict mode does? and how to change it also

Comment: nope, i'm not using strict mode. I just figured out it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're expecting to store the **obj** object to be available outside then return the obj from the runCountdown function and store it in the counters[i] array item.

```
function runCountdown(param,sessionName){
obj = new Countdown({
    seconds:param,  // number of seconds to count down
    onUpdateStatus:
        function(sec){
            Session.set(sessionName,sec);
            console.log(Session.get(sessionName));
        }, // callback for each second
    onCounterEnd: function(){ alert('counter ended!');} // final action
});

obj.start();
return obj;}
```

now in your array structure store this object in the following way -

```
counters[i] = runCountdown(diff, queryResult[i]._id);
```