# How to convert date-time difference into countdown?

Tags: php, datetime, countdown

Using this I can get the date and time difference.

```
$first_date = new DateTime(“2012-11-30 17:03:30”);
$second_date = new DateTime(“2012-12-21 00:00:00”);

$difference = $first_date->diff($second_date);

echo format_interval($difference);
```

How can i convert it from static to run as count-down timer?

Comment: whichever is simpler

Comment: I don't know which one you find simpler, I'm not gonna write it for you.

Comment: then why you are counting difference of static date, make one current time.I did it something like you can see on you post and comment "2 mins ago", but it is a whole class.

Comment: Is this PHP code run on the command line or inside a web environment ?

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191865/code-for-a-simple-javascript-countdown-timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this jquery plugin

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.countdown.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.yourCountdownContainer').countdown({
        date: "June 7, 2087 15:03:26"
    });
});
</script>
```

Form more details [enter link description here](http://rendro.github.io/countdown/)