# setTimeout in javascript to print

Tags: javascript

I have started learning JavaScript and I thought of trying a simple count down timer but I can't figure out.

```js
function countdown() {
  var count1 = 10;
  while (count1 >= 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = count1;
    }, 1000);
    count1--;
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="main" onload="countdown()"></p>
```

The page just stops/hangs. What is wrong with it?

Comment: use `setInterval(function(){ ... })` for this

Comment: I don't think `onLoad` on the `p` element will do anything. I don't think your page is stopping or hanging; it's not doing anything to start with. Try adding `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', countdown);`, then you can debug the rest of your logic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code for a simple JavaScript countdown timer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191865/code-for-a-simple-javascript-countdown-timer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use setInterval for timers, then clear it when the countdown reaches to 0. Make sure to use an immediately invoked anonymous function or execute the named function immediately upon defining. Your function will not execute otherwise, so no timer for you.

```js
function countdown() {
  var count1 = 10;
  var myTimer = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = count1;
    count1--;
    if (count1 == 0) {
      clearInterval(myTimer);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
countdown();
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: You might want to improve that code a bit, as it stands, it won't work any better than the original code in the question.

Comment: much better now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setInterval` instead, so it gets called regulary, and counting down (decreading the counter)  should happen within the function called by `setInterval`. You can omit the loop then, just call `clearInterval` when then counter reaches 0.

Answer (score 0):

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) executes the function only once. Using `setInterval` can help here.

But another point to note is about scoping of variables here. While the `setTimeOut` waits for 1 sec, the `while` loop will keep executing along, changing the value of `count1`.

The value of `count1` will be -1 all the time. Using an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) is whats needed.

```
function countdown()
{
    var count1 = 10;
    while( count1 >= 0) {
      var myTimer = setInterval((function() {
        console.log(count1);
      }(count1)), 1000);
      count1 = count1 - 1;
    }
}
countdown()
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c86y8btk/)

Comment: You should recheck your code - it definitely doesn't do what OP wants, considering that it invokes all 10 `setInterval`s immediately in a while loop.

Comment: @Hozefa Thanks for the explanation but the code is wrong.

Comment: @psh Oh yeah, there is a mistake. But I hope to get the concept at large