# Convert JavaScript function to class with callback methods

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to convert the following function to a class in JavaScript (original function from [CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5445/cms) created [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192001/177416)),

```
function Countdown(options) {
  var timer,
  instance = this,
  seconds = options.seconds || 10,
  updateStatus = options.onUpdateStatus || function () {},
  counterEnd = options.onCounterEnd || function () {};

  function decrementCounter() {
    updateStatus(seconds);
    if (seconds === 0) {
      counterEnd();
      instance.stop();
    }
    seconds--;
  }

  this.start = function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = 0;
    seconds = options.seconds;
    timer = setInterval(decrementCounter, 1000);
  };

  this.stop = function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
  };
}
```

With this usage,

```
var myCounter = new Countdown({  
    seconds:5,  // number of seconds to count down
    onUpdateStatus: function(sec){console.log(sec);}, // callback for each second
    onCounterEnd: function(){ alert('counter ended!');} // final action
});

myCounter.start();
```

My attempt is,

```
Countdown: class {
    constructor(options) {
        this.seconds = options.seconds || 10;
        this.updateStatus = options.onUpdateStatus || function () { };
        this.counterEnd = options.onCounterEnd || function () { };
        this.instance = this;
        this.timer = null;
    }

    decrementCounter() {
        this.updateStatus(this.seconds);
        if (this.seconds === 0) {
            this.counterEnd();
            this.instance.stop();
        }
        this.seconds--;
    }

    start() {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
        this.timer = 0;
        this.timer = setInterval(this.decrementCounter, 1000);
    }

    stop () {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    }
}
```

And calling it like this,

```
var counter = new Countdown({  
    seconds:5,  // number of seconds to count down
    onUpdateStatus: function(sec) {
        $("#timer").text(sec);
    }, // callback for each second
    onCounterEnd: function() {
        closeModal();
    } // final action
});
counter.start();
```

It's throwing this error in `decrementCounter()`,

> Uncaught TypeError: this.updateStatus is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use arrow functions

Comment: Thanks, @Dimensionless. Please elaborate.

Comment: Either you will have to manually bind this to all the methods inside the class to have access to `this` as suggested by @Taki in his answer or use arrow function `func = () => {}` which will automatically do that for you.

Comment: Sorry, @Dimensionless. Do you mind providing a concrete example from my code? Thanks

Comment: you can also get rid of of `this.instance = this` as that will be redundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` refers to the global object which doesn't have `updateStatus`, because the `setInterval` function doesn't preserve the `this`-context.

Use [bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/what-is-the-use-of-the-javascript-bind-method) in the constructor to fix it:

> Bind creates a new function that will have `this` set to the first parameter passed to `bind()`.

```
constructor(options) {
    this.seconds = options.seconds || 10;
    this.updateStatus = options.onUpdateStatus || function() {};
    this.counterEnd = options.onCounterEnd || function() {};
    this.instance = this;
    this.timer = null;

    this.decrementCounter = this.decrementCounter.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, @Taki; that fixed it. What is `bind` doing?

Comment: @Alex i should've elaborated more on that, I updated the answer with a link with a good explanations

Answer (score 1):

In javascript classes, if you use regular old function `functionName() { }` the function doesn't have access to `this` of the class inside the function as they have their own `this`. You will have to manually bind `this` to that function inside the constructor to have access to classes `this`.

```
contructor() {
  this.decrementCounter = this.decrementCounter.bind(this);
}
```

As you can see this will become repetitive soon as you will have to do that for each method inside the class. To help with that you can use `es6` arrow functions.

```
decrementCounter = () => {}
```

`es6` arrow function automagically binds `this` to its parent scope so that you can access parents `this` inside the methods.

My explanation is not accurate but it goes like that.

I will attach a link to a better explanation when I find one.

Comment: Good explanation, @Dimensionless.